# How to be notified when CachedModeledFramework is initialized

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using Apache Curator's [CachedModeledFramework](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/x/async/modeled/cached/CachedModeledFramework.html) to try to cache all of the child nodes in a path.  I want to be notified when the cache is loaded.  If children exist, I do get the NODE_ADDED events from the listener, but I can't find any way to get notified when it is fully cached, even if no children exist yet.  I can't use readThrough or readThroughAsZNode because the ZPath is not resolved.

Also, the `modeledClient.cached()` line produces a "CuratorCache does not support custom ExecutorService" warning even though I am not passing in an executor (same warning shows up if I do pass an executor).

```
private static final ModelSpec<Monitor> monitorSpec = ModelSpec.builder(ZPath.parseWithIds("/monitors/{id}"), JacksonModelSerializer.build(Monitor.class)).build();

private CachedModeledFramework<Monitor> cached;

public void init() {
    AsyncCuratorFramework async = AsyncCuratorFramework.wrap(CuratorMgr.getClient());
    ModeledFramework<Monitor> modeledClient = ModeledFramework.wrap(async, monitorSpec);
    cached = modeledClient.cached();
    cached.start();
    cached.listenable().addListener((type, path, stat, model) -> {  
        logger.info("LISTENER {}  {}",  type, path);
    });
}
```

### Edit

I found the answer.  The [ModeledCacheListener](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/x/async/modeled/cached/ModeledCacheListener.html) has an initialized method I can override.

```
cached.listenable().addListener(new ModeledCacheListener<Monitor>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(ModeledCacheListener.Type type, ZPath path, Stat stat, Monitor model) {
        logger.info("LISTENER {}  {}",  type, path);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialized() {
        ModeledCacheListener.super.initialized();
        logger.info("INITIALIZED");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited the initial post with the answer of overriding the initialized method of [ModeledCacheListener](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/x/async/modeled/cached/ModeledCacheListener.html)